# I can not access second monitor anymore

Tags: 18.04, error-handling, multiple-monitors

I wanted to remove mouse stickiness while using dual monitors on 18.04 version. I tried different methods to do so. Now, although the second (the main monitor) is displayed. the mouse doe not move to the main monitor at all. Currently, I am using a single monitor which happens to be a secondary monitor. It means I canm not even shut down my computer properly as as all the controls are being displayed on the monitor which I am unable to play with. Any clue on how to solve this issue?

Thanks